# RESTful page needs both GET and PUT?

Tags: rest, get, put

My web site has a design where a grid of records is shown. For each record the user might edit it (a GET request) or change its status (this *should* be a PUT).  Do I have a way of doing this without using Javascript?

That is, my current options are:

- Use Javascript in a link handler to change the request type as needed.
- Separate the GET and PUT activities to separate web pages.
- Do the status change via a GET and turn a blind eye to REST specifications right here.

Are there other options?

Thanks,
Jerome.

Comment: How's changing a record's status not an edit? And a GET request should never change a resource.

Comment: The status change **is** an edit, as I said.  It is a last-resort to using the RESTful URI and no Javascript.  Based on things, I can't get everything I asked for.  However, I now plan on using a Javascript date formatter, so I'd use option 1) above.

Answer (score 1):

A GET should not have any side-effects and a PUT would replace the whole resource at the location given by the URI. So the former should be a POST. The latter should be as well, unless it does in fact send the whole resource. A POST is possible without Javascript, obviously.